# What does this three-number notation mean in football?

Tags: football, terminology

What does 0-0-1 and 1-0-0 mean in this notation for two teams at a tournament?

> Germany (0-0-1, 0 points) vs. Sweden (1-0-0, 3 points)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In association football, people usually denote first number of wins, then number of draws, and then number of losses.

So, in this case it means 0 wins, 0 draws, 1 loss for Germany and 1 win, 0 draws, 0 losses for Sweden.